# How can one define parallel transport on lie groups?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to transport a tangent vector $T_p$ at a point $p$ to some other point $q$ on a lie group. Do I have to use $log(p^{-1}q)$, which is also a tangent vector, to achieve the same?

Comment: Parallel transport with respect to what connection?

Comment: With respect to the Riemannian connection.

Comment: What metric? Presumably the left- or right-invariant metric, perhaps bi-invariant if $G$ is, for example, compact. In that case, the answer is particularly nice.

Comment: The manifold under consideration is  $SO(3)$, i.e space of rotation matrices, where the metric can be bi-invariant I guess. But I am looking for a general answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be a Lie group. For all $g,h\in G$ there is a canonical linear isomorphism $T_gG\to T_hG$ defined as follows. For $a\in G$ let $L_a:G\to G$ be left translation by $a$, i.e. $L_a(b)=ab$. Specializing with $a=hg^{-1}$ and taking the derivative of $L_a$ we get a linear map
$$dL_{hg^{-1}}:T_gG\to T_hG.$$
This is an isomorphism since $dL_{g^{-1}h}$ is an inverse.

**Note:** Using these facts one can show that Lie groups are *parallelizable* meaning that $TG$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle $G\times\mathfrak{g}$, where $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$.

Comment: May I ask, suppose that $G$ is equipped with a Riemannian structure. For which curves $\gamma$ connecting $g$ to $h$ do we have the parallel transportation along $\gamma$ is equal to this canonical linear isomorphism?